# ASP.NET MVC 5 to remain only one unique row(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

Guys. I need an advice from you.
I created project MVC 5 and there user is importing excel file to (sql table) through interface on page. To give other users information about statuses.
In excel file 3 column ( in my model same columns )

```
Id  NoAccount Status
```

User which uploading every week gets an excel file and importing file(s) using interface on page.
In excel file same columns may contain same data or newer data (with different statuses each week)
For example on 1st week user importing excel file with following data

```
Id NoAccount Status
1  A12345      0
```

On 2nd week user importing excel file with the next data.

```
Id NoAccount Status
1  A12345      1
```

For that moment, i will have, in my sql table 2 rows 
And in a page also will be 2 rows and for preventing to confuse user should see only one row with status 1 (or 2,3 if it was )

Comment: Are you asking for help or opinion? What's your question?

Comment: How can i achive it. What  the method will be ?

Comment: @whitefang Whats your expections here, what do you mean by "How can i achive it. What the method will be"

Comment: What have you tried so far. Where's your code?

Comment: I stucked, i dont know from what i should start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep multiple rows per account in your database *and* you want to see the highest value of status for each account, you can get the data using SQL like this

```
select NoAccount, max(Status)
from table
group by NoAccount
```

Comment: I can create a view of that query than i will create another model to link with that view in database. And i will achieve my goal right steps :D?

Answer (score 1):

You mention T-SQL. You can use `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT` constructs depending on the other fields that you want to include. So, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   Id, NoAccount, Status
FROM
    MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT
    Id, NoAccount, Status, COUNT(Id)
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
   Id, NoAccount, Status
```

would give you the distinct values together with the count of duplicates.